# ASP.NET : Email format inside global resource file

Tags: asp.net

i am using email feature for registration where password is going to be send by email.

I am using following code

```
using System.Net.Mail;
MailMessage objMsg = new MailMessage();
        objMsg.IsBodyHtml = false;
        objMsg.From = new MailAddress(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["AdminMailID"].ToString());
        objMsg.To.Add(new MailAddress(txtEmail.Text.Trim()));
        objMsg.Subject = "Your registration information.";
        string emailFormat = Resources.MasterResource.emailformat.ToString();
        emailFormat = emailFormat.Replace("USERNAME", txtName.Text);
        emailFormat = emailFormat.Replace("pUNAME", txtLoginID.Text.Trim().ToLower());
        emailFormat = emailFormat.Replace("pPASSWORD", password);
        emailFormat = emailFormat.Replace("pConsumerNumber", txtConsumerNumber.Text.Trim().ToLower());
        emailFormat = emailFormat.Replace("pConsumerName", txtName.Text.Trim());
        objMsg.Body = emailFormat;

        SmtpClient objSmtpClient = new SmtpClient(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["SmtpServer"].ToString(), 25);
        objSmtpClient.Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["SmtpServerAuthenticatePassword"].ToString(), ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["SmtpServerAuthenticateUser"].ToString());
        try
        {
            objSmtpClient.Send(objMsg);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw new Exception(GetLocalResourceObject("SMTPError").ToString());
        }
        finally
        { }
```

**According to above code, following are the key points**
1. Email format is text not HTML
2. The body of mail is placed inside globalresourse file

**Problem area**
1. There are paragraph implemented in mail body  How it happens in text format.
2. My mail body have break line 
 how can i implement in text format

Please help?

[Edit]
How can we write hyperlink inside text mail.

Important  point is that i have written mail body inside master resource file? I not getting how can we write character for above mentioned points

Answer (score 1):

Don't invent your own technique to do this- use the [MailDefinition](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.maildefinition.aspx) class. One example can be [found here](http://dotnetlog.com/archive/2006/07/25/using-maildefinition-object-to-send-templated-emails-in-asp.net-2.0.aspx).

Comment: Thanks for that, I hadn't heard of that and was just about preparing to write my own for a new project. You never stop learning...

Comment: I have not implemented my own. I am using System.Net.Mail; for email. The point where i struct is that where i am not able replacement of <br><a href> and <p>.
Also i store my message text inside global resource file.

I would like to know how should i insert above characters inside global resource file for mail text format. Any example

Comment: @Hemant. You have created your own templating functionality- MailDefinition provides templating functionality for you.

Comment: What if I don't require/want a reference to System.Web? Also, http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0002kwb2.aspx specifies that a Control is required which might not be great depending on your situation. I for e.g. would like to send a template'd email from a console-hosted WCF service.

Answer (score 0):

For break line, use \n or \r\n, I guess.
For paragraph, just use break line to separate them all.

text file is text like in notepad.